# spring-boot mongodb ssh tunnel

Tags: spring, mongodb, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, ssh-tunnel

I've created a mongodb setup using the AWS cloudplatform quickstart found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/mongodb/deployment.html. I can successfully connect to my from my EC2 instance, so it has been set up properly.

Since I need to connect to it through my spring application, I need to set up an SSH tunnel through the EC2 instance to the mongodb nodes.

The only related answers I could find were using mysql and some sort of DataSource object that required a schema parameter (which I don't have, database will be full of different sorts of entities), so I was unsure of how to proceed.

**My questions:**

1. How do I set up the SSH tunnel? How do I pass in my .pem key file?
2. How will my application.properties look like for connecting to DB?

Answer (score 2):

I setup a bastion in my private subnet and using ssh tunnel to access my MongoDb Cluster through git-bash:

~/.ssh/config

```
Host bastion-host-mongo-forward
User ec2-user
Port 22
IdentityFile ~/admin.pem
HostName ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com

Localforward 3307 ip-10-50-2-24.ec2.internal:27017
Localforward 3308 ip-10-50-3-143.ec2.internal:27017
Localforward 3309 ip-10-50-3-103.ec2.internal:27017
```

start the tunnel:

```
ssh bastion-host-mongo-forward
```

After that you can setup your application.yaml and target the uri:

```
spring:
    profiles: local
    data:
       mongodb:
          uri: mongodb://user:password@localhost:3307,localhost:3308,localhost:3309/databaseName
```